Triangle formed by the tangents of a circle
Consider a triangle formed by the tangents of a circle. 
Let, the radius of the inscribed circle be $r$. Then I am trying to find the triangle with minimum area with radius $r$ fixed. Using law of sines, we can relate $r$ with the radius of circumscribed circle, $R$.
$$R  =\frac{a}{2 \sin(A)} = \frac{b}{2 \sin(B)} = \frac{c}{2 \sin(C)} $$
$$r = 4R \sin(A/2) \sin(B/2) \sin(C/2) $$
The area of the triangle is
$$ \text{Area} = \frac{1}{2} b \;c \;\sin(A/2) $$
Using some trigonometric manipulations, I was able to arrive at
$$ \text{Area} = r^2 \cot\left(\frac{A}{2}\right) \cot\left(\frac{B}{2}\right) \tan\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right) $$
But, I am not able to reduce the area to a single variable so that I can use single variable Calculus to minimize it.

You have 2 degrees of freedom here: you can choose an arbitrary pont $A$ outside of the circle, then you still can choose a point $B$ on one semi-axe passing by $A$ after the tangent to the circle. And then the point $C$ can be found uniquely. So it is no surprise that the area depends on 2 distinct variables. You should try what give $\frac{\partial Area}{\partial A}$ and $\frac{\partial Area}{\partial B}$

Yves, I guess so. I think Serge is right. This is a two variable problem and would involve partial derivatives

@YvesDaoust: indeed: I was thinking about two very long intersecting line segments, touching that small circle, making up for a triangle with a very large surface. By lowering the length of those segments, you can easily understand that the equilateral triangle should be the optimal case.

This may help:
Consider an equilateral triangle constructed about some circle. Now, consider any other tangent as an alternate point to anchor a side, such as $T$, whose tangent intersects $AB,BC$ at $A',C'$. The point $F$ where the tangent meets $CA$ must lie on the side of the angle bisector $BI$ towards $T$, hence always $AF<FC$. So if we draw a parallel to $AB$ at $C$ the similar triangles formed demonstrate that the area we lose in the triangle ($AA'F$) is always exceeded by the area gained ($CC'F$). This proof works for isosceles triangles in general. Thus any scalene triangle's area is minimized by moving a base to make it isosceles. Hence the equilateral has the smallest area of all triangles.

